# Using application on another partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I have Linux Mint, then installed Ubuntu on another partition of the HDD: is there a way to use the libraries and applications in Linux Mint from Ubuntu?

For example, I have Spotify on the first partition and I want to use it on Ubuntu, like in Windows when you use applications on the D: partition while the Windows is on the C: partition.

Comment: No, it's not a matter of partitions, it's a matter of different OSes. In your Windows example you're using the same OS, not two different Windows installations.

Comment: I know that this isn't what you aren't looking for, but if you can't do this but want some of the default applications from Linux Mint that you are used to, you can find the package name by using `apt-cache search example` and then installing it on your other partition with `sudo apt install example`.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not as easy and maybe even not recommended, but you can try to run your commands into a chroot.

```
sudo chroot /path/where/mounted/your/os
<run your command>
exit
```